# Google Analytics-Unable to track the value obtained via an ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-analytics

I am facing a problem in tracking the response of a button clicked in google analytics.Once you click the button the function fires an Ajax call and fetches the value and put that value in the  tag.I need to get the value of that particular  tag.I have created a custom JS in Google tag manager as follows:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  var track = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML;
    return track;
}, 3000);
```

hoping the ajax call takes upto 3 seconds to fetch the value and this custom function would take the value after 3 seconds.But I am using this function to as Event label in google analytics.But it is not showing anything.Suggestions required.

Comment: Do you use a javascript framework for your ajax calls ? E.g. jQuery offers "global ajax handlers" that can execute callbacks when the ajax call was successful. That would be more reliable than timeouts.

Comment: No google tag manager does not allow any other library except Javascript.When I click on a button an <h2> is filled with some text.I need the value of that.

Comment: "Google Tag Manager does not allow any other library" - that's a strange idea. GTM works fine with JS libraries.